# Aligned Views: Change position of Anchor and update aligned View's position

Tags: android, android-layout, runtime, android-view

I'm generating my Views programatically, so there's no XML. But as it is easier to show my problem, I will give the structure in XML-like notation

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:maxWidth="300dp"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Some long Text" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left">
</RelativeLayout>
```

For this, the LinearLayout is positioned in the top left corner of the RelativeLayout. The ImageView is positioned right to it.
The TextView is very important. You see it's width is variable but to a maximum of 300dp. With this and maxLines this TextView has a maximum area by the size of `300dp x 3 lines`. Most likely, the TextView won't be this large and by the `wrap_content` settings, TextView and LinearLayout will adapt to the text.
(I have to say, I overrid the TextView's `onMeasure` method, so the TextView is only as wide as the widest line.)
At the moment, everything is ok. The TextView and therefor LinearLayout enclose the text tightly, sitting at (0, 0). Next to it on the right sits the ImageView. Now comes the hard part I'm stuck at.

I want to align the LinearLayout within the before mentioned area, the TextView could maximally span. First thought was, I surround the LinearLayout with another RelativeLayout, by the maximum size and position the smaller LinearLayout within. But as the ImageView **must** have to be a direct child of *mainLayout*, I can't align it to the LinearLayout anymore.
My current approach is to override the LinearLayout's `onLayout` method:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top,
                                         int right, int bottom){

    super.onLayout(changed, this.getLeft(), this.getTop(),
                            this.getRight(), this.getBottom());

    int translation;
    int widthNeed = this.mLinLay.getMeasuredWidth();

    switch(this.mLinLayAlignment)
    {
        case Left:
            break;
        case Center:
            translation = (this.mLabWidth - widthNeed)/2;
            this.setLeft(this.getLeft() + translation);
            this.setRight(this.getRight() + translation);
            // also tried: this.setTranslationX(translation);
            break;
        case Right:
            translation = (this.mLabWidth - widthNeed);
            this.setLeft(this.getLeft() + translation);
            this.setRight(this.getRight() + translation);
            // also tried: this.setTranslationX(translation);
            break;
    }
}
```

I only want to align the LinearLayout horizontally by now, so I only distinguish between 3 cases. The translation works pretty well, but the ImageView stays on its place, where it aligns to the initial position of the LinearLayout. I first tried `LinearLayout.setTranslationX()` but with the same effect. So I changed it, because the documentation on `setTranslationX` implicated, translation happens after layouting.
I think I just have to call the right method, so *mainLayout* is forced to layout the ImageView again, but I can't find it.
Also, are these the proper way and place to move the LinearLayout? As I need the final size of the TextView, it had to be measured, <del>so this is the place I have to do it, I think.</del>

**EDIT**
I have tried a little more. I got the LayoutParams from the LinearLayout, increased the left and decreased the right Margin by the calculated translation and set the LayoutParams again. Well, the ImageView still stays in place, so no progress here. But after switching out and back in the app, I realised, the Margin changed every time layouting. Well, should have seen this coming.
But why isn't the same thing happening, using setLeft and setRight?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you draw a picture of what you want it would help.

I would stay out of the onLayout method alltogether.

If you want to move View or Layout around, then use layout params

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = linearLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: This would be a nice solution, but RelativeLayout.LayoutParams doesn't offer the fields `x` and `y`. I think these were used by AbsoluteLayout, which is deprecated.

Comment: sorry, you are right. Not sure why eclipse didnt say anything. Use the set margin values as in my edited answer. Please stay out of the onlayout method. It will just cause headaches.

    **setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)**

is means for exactly this reason.

Comment: In fact, I'm using setMargin() now. But the problem is, I have to set the margin dependent on the width of the containing Views. But these are not available, until onLayout is called. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I have read your question again, and am still not exactly sure what you want. Is the problem that you want the imageview to always be directly to the right of the text view, and move with it as the text changes?

It would be useful if you posted a picture illustrating your requirements.